# How to add a new link for my custom module page to the top horizontal menu in Prestashop 1.6.4

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I created a module in which it will hook to one of the pages. But how to display the Link of  my custom module to the top horizontal menu in Prestashop 1.6.  i.e when I Navigate to Modules -> Modules and looking up for Top horizontal menu. and when I Click the Configure button to access the module configuration page  how can  I  see  my module link in the available Items lists. i.e  see the image in the Available Items I want my custom  link. Link of my custom module  which i developed . i.e when my custom module is installed  the link must appear  here in the Available Items ,So that I can add  my custom  link the selected item [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two choices:

- **create it by hand in the backoffice**

  In the blocktopmenu module configuration page you can create a new custom link under `ADD A NEW LINK` block. The link to your module will be `/module/your_module_name/your_controller_name`. Then you will be able to add this link to your menu under `MENU TOP LINK`.
- **create it programmatically**

  In the install method of your module you can create this custom link using blocktopmenu methods.

  ```php
  if (Module::isInstalled("blocktopmenu"))
  {
      // You will have to put the right path in here
      require_once('../blocktopmenu/menutoplinks.class.php');

      $languages = $this->context->controller->getLanguages();
      $shops = Shop::getContextListShopID();

      $links_label = array();
      $labels = array();

      foreach ($languages as $key => $val)
      {
          // You need to replace "my_module" and "my_controller" to get a link to your controller
          $links_label[$val['id_lang']] = Context::getContext()->link->getModuleLink("my_module", "my_controller");
          // Here set your link label for the menu
          $labels[$val['id_lang']] = "My Link Name";
      }

      foreach ($shops as $shop_id)
      {
          $added = MenuTopLinks::add($links_label, $labels, 0, (int) $shop_id);
          // You can check wether $added is true or false

      }
  }
  ```
- **create it programmatically with auto-suppression**

  ```php
  public function install()
  {
      if (! parent::install())
      {
          return false;
      }

      if (Module::isInstalled("blocktopmenu"))
      {
          // You will have to put the right path in here
          require_once('../blocktopmenu/menutoplinks.class.php');

          $languages = $this->context->controller->getLanguages();
          $shops = Shop::getContextListShopID();

          foreach ($shops as $shop_id)
          {

              $links_label = array();
              $labels = array();

              foreach ($languages as $key => $val)
              {
                  // You need to replace "my_module" and "my_controller" to get a link to your controller
                  $links_label[$val['id_lang']] = Context::getContext()->link->getModuleLink("my_module", "my_controller", array(), null, $val['id_lang'], $shop_id);
                  // Here set your link label for the menu
                  $labels[$val['id_lang']] = "My Link Name";
              }

              $added = MenuTopLinks::add($links_label, $labels, 0, (int) $shop_id);

              if ($added) {
                  $link_id = Db::getInstance()->getValue("
                      SELECT DISTINCT id_linksmenutop
                      FROM `"._DB_PREFIX_."linksmenutop_lang`
                      WHERE link LIKE '" . $link . "'
                      AND id_shop LIKE '" . $shop_id . "'
                  ");

                  Configuration::set("MY_MODULE_LINKS_TOP_" . $shop_id, $link_id);
              }
          }
      }
  }

  public function uninstall()
  {
      if (! parent::uninstall())
      {
          return false;
      }

      if (Module::isInstalled("blocktopmenu"))
      {
          // You will have to put the right path in here
          require_once('../blocktopmenu/menutoplinks.class.php');

          $shops = Shop::getContextListShopID();

          foreach ($shops as $shop_id)
          {
              $link_id = Configuration::get("MY_MODULE_LINKS_TOP_" . $shop_id);

              if ($link_id !== false)
              {
                  MenuTopLinks::remove($link_id, $shop_id);
              }
          }
      }
  }
  ```

  Code no tested but must be working with Prestashop 1.6.

Comment: Ok Its working and I set  the path correctly require_once('/../blocktopmenu/menutoplinks.class.php');

But when I uninstall my module from BO the links are not getting removed So how  to remove this Do I need to put something in uninstall also ? @Florian Lemaitre

Comment: yes, on your uninstall method use `MenuTopLinks::remove($id_linksmenutop, $id_shop)` to remove your links

Comment: Hi @JerryAbraham won't you mind accepting this answer to mark this thread as solved? Or do you need any more informations?

Comment: Yes I will mark accepted soon also one more information  ,I need is that  when I uninstall the module how will I  remove the link?

Comment: I've added an example of uninstall. It's not a clean solution because `MenuTopLinks::add()` doesn't return the newly added element's id. So we need to query the database to get it.

Comment: I've also added `id_shop` and `id_lang` to the link generation. This code has not been tested ;)

Comment: $link is not sent on SELECT DISTINCT. What should be set?